# Reducing image size on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, images, jpeg

I have a scanned JPG file and due to high quality scanning, the file size is large. What I would like to do is reduce the image size of the file, keeping the jpg format, but losing Quality obviously.

Would I be able to do this using existing Windows Graphics editing tool such as paint brush?

In any case, how would I be able to achieve this quickly?

Comment: The quick and nasty solution would be to [resize](http://www.thetechrepo.com/main-articles/444) the image in Windows Paint.

Comment: Which version of Windows do you have? MS Paint in XP is horrible and doesn't handle JPG files very well. Windows 7 version is much better.

Comment: Also, do you mean resize the image (pixel dimension) or reduce the file size (lower quality for same pixel dimension)?

Comment: @Shevek: Sorry, I re-tagged the question from windows-xp to windows, because the OP didn't mention a version in his post. Maybe I shouldn't have.

Comment: @Shevek: I am on Windows XP.

Comment: @Karolos, true, but try to make edits more substantive in the future.

Comment: @soandos: Ok. I'm pretty new to editing. Thanks for your suggestion; I will refrain from doing minor edits next time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Batch Conversion/Rename in [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) works wonders for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [Batch Picture Resize](http://www.rw-designer.com/picture-resize), which is very easy to use, and free. I used it many times in the past. You can either choose your option by the menu, or renaming the file to set the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use one of the image resizing shell extentions - microsoft has a powertoy for windows xp that does it ( [download link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=211477) )and there's [options for newer versions of windows as well](http://imageresizer.codeplex.com/). Almost no UI cruft, and almost instant in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Paint.Net is a good intermediate image editor (between paint and professional tools). It can adjust the quality to reduce the size.

Comment: As great as Paint.Net is for editing it's abilities for reducing the size/quality of jpg's (and alike) are bit cumbersome. I wish Paint.Net had batch conversion built it.

Answer (score 0):

A free, open source and specially written for Windows is http://imageresizer.codeplex.com/ It can do batch resize, too.

If you want to resize only one file, of course, Paint can do it. Just take a look in the menu of Paint.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools to do this.

If you are using Windows 7 (question does not specify) then Windows Paint is adequate for this task.

If you are using Windows XP then avoid Windows Paint completely as it is not very good with JPG files.

Microsoft's own [Image Resizer PowerToy](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-xp?T1=PT) adds simple right click options to Windows Explorer (link doesn't work in Chrome, open this one in IE)

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) is an image viewer which has conversion tools

[Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/) is an updated version of MS Paint with many extra features

Google's [Picasa](http://picasa.google.co.uk/) is an image library program with built in editing features

[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) is a fully fledged image editor which aims to be as much like PhotoShop as possible

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't see it yet, I might as well throw in **Microsoft Office Picture Manager**. If you have MS Office then most likely, you already have this installed. I'm not even sure if it requires MS office to be installed in the first place.

If you can't locate it easily, I believe you can simply open up the **Run...** prompt (*Start > Run **OR** Windows Key + R*) and type in **OIS** and press **OK**

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a free online photo editor like [fotoflexer](http://fotoflexer.com). No need to create an account. Open it, upload photo, click resize, select your size (preset or manual). Save back to your computer. Nothing installed.

Comment: Or http://resizemyimage.net is doing the same

Answer (score 0):

[FastStone Photo Resizer](http://www.faststone.org) does resizing and a lot more. very easy to use batch processor.

Answer (score 0):

**Caesium**

*Compression up to 90% without visual quality loss (almost...)*

http://caesium.sourceforge.net/